# Basic Embedded Firmware testing essentials and Software Test plan

Tags: embedded, testing, firmware

I am trying to make an embedded product, but I'm new to firmware testing and want to make sure I don't miss anything. What are the things that need to be checked for its firmware performance?

Proper watchdog timer is one thing to be checked. Flash/RAM usage could be another. What else needs to be checked for making sure the product has "good" firmware?

I mostly deal with PICs and C compilers.

Comment: A book could be written on this. Are there any safety considerations where improper operation could damage people or property?

Comment: It very much depends on the product, is it a dancing monkey or an autopilot?

Comment: Testing is the job of anything from sophisticated equipmemt, to a QA team of engineers, to a intern, to customers, depending on what the product is, its cost, cost of failure, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of these are more idiot-checks of the code than actual testing procedures, but they're good to do anyway.

- **Make sure you have good specs**. If you have clear specs for every possible variable that matters for your project, testing should just be a matter of comparing against the spec. It never is, but it's a nice goal. One thing that sometimes gets left out of specs is *response time*. If your system does as its told, but it takes a second instead of a millisecond, you still don't have a good system.
- Test each individual piece of the firmware separately. Make sure the
  A/D converters work, make sure the lights turn on as commanded, make
  sure each input works, make sure each output works, make sure the
  timers work. *Then* start worrying about how it all works together.
  It's almost certain the firmware won't work on the first pass, and
  you'll have to break it down into pieces anyway. Best to start there.
- Turn the board on and off many dozens times and make sure everything
  starts up properly on a consistent basis. Probably a good idea to
  watch all the power rails on a scope and make sure all the regulators
  start up. Do this with every possible combination of inputs and power
  supplies. This tests both your hardware and your software.
- Expose the unit to EMI/RFI noise. I typically take an AC hipot tester
  and short it to itself to generate high-voltage low-current sparks.
  Wreaks havoc on circuits lacking noise immunity. (Plus, dragging the
  sparks along the chassis makes you feel like a tiny version of
  Emperor Palpatine. But maybe that's just me.) This tests both your
  hardware and your software.
- Look for all possible cases of division or modulus by a variable.
  Make sure you can never, ever divide or mod by a variable that could
  possibly be set to zero.
- Look for all pointers, and make sure that none of the thousand things
  you can do wrong with pointers can possibly happen.
- Look for all arrays, and make sure you can never run off the end of
  the array.
- Look for all instances of what you intended to be comparison (==) and
  make sure they're not assignment (=). A helpful regexp for this would
  be: (.+ = .+)
- Look for any occasions of EEPROM writes, and make sure to thoroughly
  test those cases. EEPROM is *slow*, so multiple EEPROM writes in
  series might slow down other time-critical processes. This could
  simply trip your watchdog timer and cause a reset, or (in the case of
  a switching power supply) this could cause an explosion because your
  outputs didn't get updated properly.
- If you're using any interrupts at all, try not to unless absolutely
  necessary. They increase the number of possible unexpected code
  interactions dramatically. If you have to use interrupts, consider
  what happens if the interrupt happens at every possible point in the
  execution of your program. Also, consider every possible *nesting* of
  interrupts, or just disable nested interrupts so you don't have to
  worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Test EVERY feature in as many unique corner case combinations and scenarios as technically feasible. Anything less and you may be delivering a faulty product.

Comment: And even then, you'll probably still miss one somewhere.

Comment: Technically feasible or Financially feasible? depends on the return on investment strategy that applies .... For a throw away product I would test the big issues and the easy stuff. For the £/$ 2000 to ship it back at the manufacturers cost in the warranty period… Ask how big the budget is!